# AXLAPIService Cisco Unified Communications Manager

Tags: cisco, cisco-axl, cucm

Hello I am trying to get a list of calls that were placed to a specific phone number, is this possible using the api? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess "using the api" you mean AXL? No you can't you need to use the Call Detail Records. You will find a nice explanation in Cisco community forum [here](https://community.cisco.com/t5/collaboration-voice-and-video/understanding-cdr-call-detail-records/ta-p/3112476).

Basically you can view the CDR using the Cisco Unified Real-Time Monitoring Tool (RTMT).

You find this tool in your CUCM under `"Advanced Features" -> "Plugins"`.

How ever you can instruct your CUCM to upload the CDR Files every X Minutes to one of your servers via FTP or SFTP. There you can have a cron-job which parses those files into a database to make the easier to use.

You can setup the CDR Upload in the "Cisco Unified Serviceability" under `"Tools" -> "CDR Magement"`.

If you need real time information, for example because you want to send an E-Mail for every missed call, then you can use the "Cisco Unified JTAPI".

You will find this under `"Advanced Features" -> "Plugins"`. How ever then you need to read the Developers Guide and invest some coding.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a little old. But the proper place to look for received and placed calls to a phone number/IP phone on Cisco UC is the CDR records.

Look at: CDRonDemand API https://developer.cisco.com/site/sxml/discover/overview/cdr-on-demand/

Also, you can send CDR records to SFTP destination "Billing Server"
Look at this guide: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/callReportingBillingAdmin/12_5_1/cucm_b_reporting-billing-administration-guide-1251SU1/cucm_b_reporting-and-billing-administration-guide_chapter_01011.html

There are many existing applications that can ingest this data and make it easy to access. Such as this: https://www.callrecordanalyzer.com/